# Grafana with Prometheus DS: select valueX in DataX if keyInfo in (DataX and DataY)

Tags: prometheus, grafana

As the title says, with a prometheus datasource, I want to select valueX in DataX only if keyInfo is found in both (DataX and DataY). How do I construct something like this as prometheus query in grafana?

Example:

`DataX{keyInfo="device5", type="router", vendor="vendor123"}`
`DataY{keyInfo="device5", health="okay", status="in-service"}`

For all keyInfo in DataX, if keyInfo in DataY, print DataX{vendor}. In this case I'd print `vendor123`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming `keyInfo` is unique within both metrics you can use `and` with [`on()`](https://prometheus.io/docs/prometheus/latest/querying/operators/#one-to-one-vector-matches) specifying list of labels being used to pair metrics:

```
DataX and on(keyInfo) DataY
```

This will return metric `DataX` with *all* its labels. If you need only `keyInfo` you can use `sum by` to leave out all other labels.

```
sum by (keyInfo) (DataX and on(keyInfo) DataY)
```

---

If my assumption about uniqueness is incorrect, you might need [`group_left()` or `group_right()`](https://prometheus.io/docs/prometheus/latest/querying/operators/#many-to-one-and-one-to-many-vector-matches) depending on your situation.

Comment: The uniqueness assumption is accurate and this answers my question. I was able to extend this answer for a more specific solution. ```count(DataX{group="grpX"} and on(keyInfo) DataY{health="okay", status="in-service"}) by (vendor)```